# How do I establish a minimum time for thread completion?

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm using multithreading to download videos from a website, however sometimes if the video is too small, the program starts another thread too fast, and the server blocks my request.

I don't want to use time.sleep because that will slow down requests that are not required to be slowed down.

So basically I need a command to establish a minimum execution time, like.

**Pseuco code**

```
minimum time = 20 seconds
If thread ended has been completed faster than minimum time:
     wait until minimum time has been reached
```

Comment: can you show the code that does the multi-threading

Comment: Without trying something overly complex to achieve this, you could just start a timer when the thread starts. And when the thread finishes, sleep for only the remainder of time. `start = ...; <threading code>; duration = now - start; if duration < minimum: time.sleep(minimum - duration)`. Which is basically slightly less-pseudo pseudo code of what you've put in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without trying something overly complex to achieve this, you could a) start a timer when the thread starts b) when the thread finishes, sleep for only the remainder of the time needed to reach the minimum duration:

```py
start = ...
<threading code>
duration = now() - start
if duration < minimum:
    time.sleep(minimum - duration)
```

Which is basically slightly less-pseudo pseudo code of what you've got in your question.

Comment: I guess that works for me